# Преобразование значения после валидации

Tags: yii2

Собственно есть модель, на вход которой поступает два параметра **startFrom** и **startTo**. При поиске я валидирую модель, и если формат правильный то преобразовываю и добавляю в условие. Может есть какое-то стандартное или более правильное решение. Например думал может в **afterValidate** добавить преобразование.

```
public $startFrom;

public $startTo;

public function rules() {
    return [
        [['startFrom', 'startTo'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i'],
    ];
}

public function search($params) {
    $query = User::find()
        ->active()

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'forcePageParam' => false,
            'pageSizeParam' => false,
        ],
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        $query->where('0=1');

        return $dataProvider;
    }

    if (!empty($this->startFrom) && !empty($this->startTo)) {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'dttm_start', strtotime($this->startFrom), strtotime($this->startTo)]);
    } elseif (!empty($this->startFrom)) {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'dttm_start', strtotime($this->startFrom)]);
    } elseif (!empty($this->startTo)) {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'dttm_start', strtotime($this->startTo)]);
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Yii есть валидатор 'filter', который может преобразовать значение в нужный формат.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#filter

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['startFrom', 'startTo'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i'],
        [['startFrom', 'startTo'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'strtotime'],
    ];
}
```